# Getting invalid selector exception when i give the first value from the list as part of the locating that element using the selector

Tags: python

This is my code, I have given rec item (which is the first item from the list, and placed it in the selector statement. The intension is, when running the automated chrome driver, it has to click on that element with that name.

```py
for rec in recipients:  
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[title='" + recipient + "']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "main"] / footer / div[1] / div[2] / div / 
    div[2]').send_keys(message)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[3]').click()
```

but instead, I got invalid selector exception

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/archanaradhakrishnan/PycharmProjects/Gmail/whatsapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//span[contains(@title,' + '"' + recipient + '"' + ')]')
  File "/Users/archanaradhakrishnan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/Users/archanaradhakrishnan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/archanaradhakrishnan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/archanaradhakrishnan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error to see which line gives you the exception?

Comment: Hi, Added the full stack

Answer (score 1):

You get wrong from here:

```py
File "/Users/archanaradhakrishnan/PycharmProjects/Gmail/whatsapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//span[contains(@title,' + '"' + recipient + '"' + ')]')
```

You made a `for` loop through `rec in recipients`, but you call `recipient` instead.

Comment: for recipient in recipients:

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//span[contains(@title,' + '"' + recipient + '"' + ')]')

    message = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_2FbwG")
    message.send_keys(msg)

    sendButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_1U1xa")
    sendButton.click()

Comment: @AMR  Look like your class_name was auto generated on each session load. Try another stable element, like tag_name..